# "Recursive" listToString()-method in linked lists

Tags: java, string, linked-list

Currently visiting a power class due to preparations for the Java exam, we basically came up to a question:

```
    class Node{    //List node
        String text;
        Node next;
    }

    class Stringbuilder{
        ...
        void append(String s) //attaches s
        String toString()     //returns the fully built String
    }

    public static String listToString(Node first){
        //TO DO
    }
```

Our task is to define listToString. We did an iterative method that is definitely working, but I was curious about this recursive alternative:

```
    public static String listToString(Node first){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if(first == null) return "";
        String result = first.text;
        return result + sb.append(first.next.text).toString();
    }
```

So the question is: Can this work?

Comment: run the code and that will answer your question, won't it?

Comment: where is the recursion in the given method?

Comment: Let's put the question different: If my exam is gonna come up with this question how wrong will I be if I use my recursive method instead of the safe, iterative stuff?

Comment: Basically it should be within the last return argument, as I keep jumping to the next node and appending the text values via the StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing recursive in the `listToString` method you posted. It has to call itself to be recursive.

```
public static String listToString(Node first)
{
    if(first == null) return "";
    String result = first.text;
    return result + " " + listToString(first.next);
}
```

Comment: Okay, you've got a point right there, shame on me. However, would it work?

Comment: That was an answer even the course instructor couldn't give me safely, and that's why it sparked my curiosity. I'm aware that it's not recursive now, though.

Comment: @LéonTheodorZuGuttenberg I was referring to my suggested answer in my comment, not to your code.

Comment: And what would be your answer referring to my code?

Comment: @LéonTheodorZuGuttenberg Your code would only print the first two elements in the list, and it would throw a NullPointerException if the list has only one element.

Comment: I see. Right now I even see that I can't possibly make the method recursive, because that would create a Stringbuilder for each recursion, and the sense in the question (which explicitly asks to use the StringBuilder) gets lost. Good, I have my answer, thank you!